# How can I iterate through an array of days in a year in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, datetime

T. student and I have this challenge to create a program (in C#) to calculate the number of days passed in a year, without using the DayOfYear property, I'm using a windows form app with a date time picker to select the date from which to calculate, here's what I got so far,  it doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
    private void dtmSelectedDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DaysSoFarThisYear();
    }

    private void DaysSoFarThisYear()
    {
        int daysInMonth = dtmSelectedDate.Value.Day;
        int monthInYear = dtmSelectedDate.Value.Month;
        int daysSoFar = 0;

        int[,] daysOfYear = new int[daysInMonth, monthInYear];

        for (int row = 0; row < daysOfYear.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < daysOfYear.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                daysSoFar++;
            }
        }

        txtCalculated.Text = Convert.ToString(daysSoFar);

       // DateTime dayOfYear = new DateTime(dtmSelectedDate.Value.Year, dtmSelectedDate.Value.Month, dtmSelectedDate.Value.Day);
       // txtFromNET.Text = Convert.ToString(dayOfYear.DayOfYear);
    }
}
```

Comment: simplicity is a virtue my friend...........you are recreating code .NET already (in a way) provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
TimeSpan time= DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 01, 01));
int numberOfDays = time.Days;
```

Comment: good trick but you have to add one day or subtract a new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year-1,12,31) otherwise you will get a wrong day count.
e.g.
01.01.2014 - 01.01.2014 = 0 but it is still the first day in year